# Como colocar zoom em uma imageView?

Tags: android, imageview

Estou procurando a implementação de um zoom na internet mas não acho. Achei apenas um zoom que é aplicado em toda a imagem. Eu precisava deste zoom padrão que tem na maioria dos aplicativos que permite dar zoom em qualquer ponto da imagem. Alguém sabe como implementar isso? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 3):

Olha existe essa lib [aqui](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

```
ImageView mImageView;
PhotoViewAttacher mAttacher;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Any implementation of ImageView can be used!
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

    // Set the Drawable displayed
    Drawable bitmap = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wallpaper);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);

    // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the zooming functionality.
    mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(mImageView);
}


// If you later call mImageView.setImageDrawable/setImageBitmap/setImageResource/etc then you just need to call
attacher.update();
```