# Como usar mais de uma extends?

Tags: java, android, herança

Quando crio o projeto ele vem assim

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

gostaria de usar mais duma `extends`  como fazer ?

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
private ImageView imageView;
private float scale = 1f;

@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

    //Factor de zoom correspondente ao movimento feito
    float scaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();

    //Executa o zoom
    performZoom(scaleFactor);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new MainActivity());
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            v.performClick();
            //Chamar o onTouchEvent do nosso ScaleGestureDetector
            scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
     }



private void performZoom(float scaleFactor) {
    scale *= scaleFactor;
    scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5.0f));
    imageView.setScaleX(scale);
    imageView.setScaleY(scale);
}
```

}

Comment: Por que necessita disso?

Comment: @ramaral por causa disso `extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`

Comment: @ramaral o que está errado não estou conseguindo implementar

Comment: Implemente a interface Listener e delegue a execução dos métodos para a sua implementação.

Comment: *SimpleOnScaleGestureListener* não é uma *interface*. Elimine `implements SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` e declare uma *inner class* que *extends* de *SimpleOnScaleGestureListener* ou seja copie o código da classe *ScaleListener* da [outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74580/2541) para dentro da *MainActivity*

Comment: Relacionada, talvez duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22718/101

Comment: @ramaral o `view ` seria quem no código ?

Comment: É a *ImageView* onde vai ser aplicado o zoom.

Comment: @ramaral mas essa `private ImageView imageView;` ?

Comment: @ramaral deu tudo certo, mas queria fazer uma pergunta, na hora que estiver no zoom bem ampliado como movimentar a imagem com dedo para ver as outra parte da imagens ?

Comment: Pois, aí as coisas complicam! Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/109286/2541)

Answer (score 3):

Java não da suporte a mais de uma "classe pai", o mais próximo disso que você ira conseguir será derivar `extends` de uma classe e implementar `implements` quantas interfaces precisar.